# Esc and Fn keys are not working

Tags: windows-8, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've got a Packard Bell TM98 laptop. I've recently installed Windows 8 and was updated to Windows 8.1. I am not sure but I think that <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are not working from this moment. I've looked for some [keyboard driver](http://www.packardbell.es/pb/es/ES/content/download) and I downloaded LaunchManager from the support site but it hasn't fixed my problem.

I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to close the window but I can't use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to sleep the laptop.

There's no W8 drivers for my laptop, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried using the *Fn* key along with the function key itself, e.g. *Fn+Alt+F3* to set Sleep? On many laptops, there are settings, whether in the OS or in BIOS, to change the mode of the function keys for secondary operations, (volume control or screen brightness etc.) so that the *Fn* key is required for one set of operations or the other. Also, have you used the *Power Options* Control Panel applet to set the keyboard shortcut?
2. You can test the *Esc* key by pressing *Ctrl-Shift-Esc* to start *Task Manager*, or with a free keyboard test utility such as http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Keyboard-Test-Utility.shtml [this will also check the function keys]. If the *Esc* key is working, an *application* using that key may be the issue; it's doubtful you need a new keyboard driver.

Comment: [1] Fn+Alt+F3 is not working and [2] In this application, Esc key doesn't highlight when I press it. Thanks for the answer. Could I have the physical keyboard failing?

Comment: Unfortunately, the keys are not working in the test

Comment: It may be a physical keyboard issue. Borrow or buy (some are <US$5) an external USB keyboard, which Win8 should recognize immediately. If that works, then it's probably a physical keyboard issue, such as broken trace or incompletely plugged connector. Of course, an external keyboard could solve the problem, if you don't mind the addition.

Comment: Thanks for all your support! I'll try plugging an external keyboard